# Unresponsive ssh session in Manjaro / Arch Linux after using scp / rsync

Tags: ssh, rsync, manjaro, scp, sshd

I did a fresh install of Manjaro 20.2 on my laptop. Now I try to transfer files via scp / rsync between this laptop and another laptop (kubuntu 18.04) in the local network and an external server (Ubuntu 20.04, I believe).

In both cases, an initial call of rsync on my Manjaro laptop will transfer some files and then pause and finally abort:

```
laptop% rsync -rtvvvuL --progress user@webserver:/directory/ /home/user/directory/
[snip]
Timeout, server webserver not responding.
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (112760 bytes received so far) [receiver]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(228) [receiver=v3.2.3]
[receiver] _exit_cleanup(code=12, file=io.c, line=228): about to call exit(12)
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (100412 bytes received so far) [generator]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(228) [generator=v3.2.3]
[generator] _exit_cleanup(code=12, file=io.c, line=228): about to call exit(255)
rsync: [generator] write error: Broken pipe (32)
```

This also happens if rsync is called on my kubuntu laptop to sync files with Manjaro, so it doesn't matter whether the Manjaro machine is server or client.

If, after that, I try to connect via SSH to the webserver again, I am successfully authenticated, but I do not get a command prompt:

```
laptop% ssh -vvv user@webserver                                                                           
OpenSSH_8.4p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1i  8 Dec 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/user/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/home/user/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/home/user/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug2: resolving "webserver" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to webserver [123.456.789.111] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
[snip]
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
[snip]
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to webserver ([123.456.789.111]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: receive packet: type 80
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 4
debug1: Remote: /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys:4: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug3: receive packet: type 4
debug1: Remote: /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys:4: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x48
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug3: send packet: type 80
Timeout, server p000327627.pwhost.de not responding.
```

Also, if I call rsync again, it will just do nothing:

```
laptop% rsync -rtvvvuL --progress user@webserver:/directory/ /home/user/directory/
opening connection using: ssh -l user webserver rsync --server --sender -vvvuLtre.iLsfxCIvu . /directory/  (10 args)
Confirm user presence for key ECDSA-SK SHA256:[snip]
Timeout, server webserver not responding.
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(228) [Receiver=v3.2.3]
[Receiver] _exit_cleanup(code=12, file=io.c, line=228): about to call exit(12)
```

From my kubuntu machine, I can ssh/scp/rsync with the server without problem. Also, the connection from my Android to my kubuntu machine is without problem, but with Manjaro it hangs. I observed the problem in three different wifis, which makes me think it is not network-related.

The ssh/sshd config (or any configuration on the Manjaro machine) is irrelevant because I could reproduce the problem using a Manjaro 20.2 KDE Live System.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. The reason for the SSH problems was the driver for my wifi chipset. I am using Broadcom BCM4311 and installing the broadcom-wl driver solved the problem for me. I first installed the linux header packages for all installed kernels and then the broadcom-wl-dkms driver.

```
sudo pacman -Syyu
sudo pacman -S $(pacman -Qsq "^linux" | grep "^linux[0-9]*[-rt]*$" | awk '{print $1"-headers"}' ORS=' ')
sudo pacman -S broadcom-wl-dkms
```

After a reboot, the "wl" driver should be enabled, which I can confirm with this command:

```
laptop% inxi -Fxz | grep BCM4331
           Device-2: Broadcom BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n vendor: Apple AirPort Extreme driver: wl v: kernel port: efa0
```

The driver should be `wl`, **not** `bcma-pci-bridge`.

The following websites pointed me to the solution:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Broadcom_wireless#SSH_freeze_for_BCM4331_with_b43

https://archived.forum.manjaro.org/t/broadcom-wifi-driver-fails-to-install-properly/46316/2

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem with ssh hanging on a 2013 macbook pro retina display (manjaro i3 edition). I followed the commands you mentioned:

```bsh
sudo pacman -Syyu
sudo pacman -S $(pacman -Qsq "^linux" | grep "^linux[0-9]*[-rt]*$" | awk '{print $1"-headers"}' ORS=' ')
sudo pacman -S broadcom-wl-dkms
```

and my wifi stopped working. Running `sudo pacman -S broadcom-wl` fixed the wifi that I broke with the previous commands.

What worked for me was to install the linux headers (linux510-headers) that matched the kernel version that I have (Linux 5.10.42-1) after updating the system with `sudo pacman -Syyu`.