# Arch fresh install, SSH hangs and times out

Tags: ssh, arch-linux, broadcom, connman

I just finished configuring a fresh install of Arch on a Macbook Pro mid-2012 (9,2).
It has a Broadcom wireless modem (chip 4331) that works for internet browsing with my current configuration.

SSH cliennt will not connect to any host, timing out. I have tested the same connection with two OS X versions, including one on this device, a shell emulator on my iPhone and an Ubuntu linux machine and all work.

I am using connman and iwd to connect the wireless. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a clear explanation but I did solve this issue. Though the issue was not identical I followed this solution, updating, downloading linux headers and the `broadcom-wl-dkms` driver, and the problem was corrected:

```
sudo pacman -Syyu
sudo pacman -S $(pacman -Qsq "^linux" | grep "^linux[0-9]*[-rt]*$" | awk '{print $1"-headers"}' ORS=' ')
sudo pacman -S broadcom-wl-dkms
```

[Unresponsive ssh session in Manjaro / Arch Linux after using scp / rsync](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/627451/473281)

Presumably this is a driver issue, as I was using `b43` rather than `braodcom-wl-dkms`. I misdiagnosed the issue as http browsing was working fine. Some tips and suggestions that are related here under [3.3 broadcom-wl](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/broadcom_wireless).

Comment: Please edit an excerpt of the link, and not have a link-only answer which is vulnerable to rotting

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I have done so.